# How do I create different Tkinter frames across multiple files?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI on Tkinter that needs to open or close windows when buttons are pressed, and I would prefer if each window was in its own file. I tried creating a very simple example of this with the three files below.  The first window is supposed to have a button that, when pressed, closes the current window and opens the next one.  I'm currently running into a problem where the window is created but the button is not.  How do I fix this?

Main.py

```
from MyTkWindow import *

myWindow = MyTkWindow()
myWindow.start()
```

MyTkWindow.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from NextFrame import *

class MyTkWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        nextWin = NextWindow()
        NextScreen = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=lambda:[self.destroy(), nextWin.start()])
        NextScreen.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

NextFrame.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class NextWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        Leave = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: self.destroy())
        Leave.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see how this code got as far as creating a window: you certainly did not request the creation of a window anywhere.  (Calling a Frame "Window" does not make it one!)  You have to call `Tk()` to initialize it and create the initial window, you have to actually pass that as the first parameter to your Frame so that it has a defined parent, you have to call `.pack()` or other geometry management method on the Frame to actually make it visible in the window.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the indicated changes. The primary problem was due to not calling the `pack()` method of the windows/frames being created.

**`main.py`**:

```
from MyTkWindow import *

myWindow = MyTkWindow()
myWindow.pack()  # ADDED

myWindow.start()
```

**`MyTkWindow.py`**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from NextFrame import *

class MyTkWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # ADDED parent argument.
        nextWin = NextWindow()
        NextScreen = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                               command=lambda: [self.destroy(),
                                                nextWin.pack(),  # ADDED
                                                nextWin.start()])
        NextScreen.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

**`NextFrame.py`**:

```
import tkinter as tk

class NextWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # ADDED parent argument.
        Leave = tk.Button(self, text="Quit",
                          command=lambda: self.destroy())
        Leave.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

**Suggestion:** Read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) because it will make your code more understanable and maintainable. Specifically, the [**Naming Conventions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) section especially with respect to class, variable, and module file names.